# In a Designer workflow is "compare field" case sensitive?

Tags: 2007, sharepoint-designer

Whenever a field contains a keyword then a certain person needs to receive an email e.g. if "Field Name" contains "apple", email Enilorac.

Will it still send the email if "Field Name" contains "APPLE" or "Apple"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the comments on this blog post: 
[Create compact and powerful conditions in your workflows](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/sharepointdesigner/)

Extract from comments:

> Dean Gross 20 May 2008 12:36 PM Is the Contains condition Case
> Sensitive? I am having a difficulties getting a condition to evaluate
> consistently and I'm wondering if this may be the cause.
>
> Thanks
>
> Dean
>
> spdblog 21 May 2008 5:37 PM Hi dlgross,
>
> Yes, CONTAINS is case sensitive.  If you want to ignore case while
> doing a CONTAINS operation, you should use MATCHES REGULAR EXPRESSION
> instead. FYI, I have updated this article a bit since original
> publication after learning about some constraints around using
> compound conditions.
>
> Andy

So you can use Matches Regular Expressions instead, or there are some workflow designer actions available on CodePlex: 
[SharePoint Designer Workflow Extensions (custom actions)](https://web.archive.org/web/20171222200318/http://spdwfextensions.codeplex.com/)

I hope this helps

Comment: No problem... here to help ;)